Remove Column Headers from Tibble - Shiny Dashboard
I make a data frame as shown below that is then rendered to a table in a drop down menu in a shiny app. I want to remove the column headers "." and ".." due to the format of the data being in long format it does not make sense to have column headers. I have tried many options but it seems there is no way around creating a df with out column headers?

      output$rain_data <- renderTable({
        
        df <- tibble(
          . = c("Project ID", "Project Name", "Project Type", "Percent Chance of Rain", "Predicted
Rain Days", "Predicted 7-day precipitation (in)", "7-day accumulated precipitation (in)"),
          .. = c("123", "123", "123", "123","123","123", "123"))


I have tried placing NULL for column headers and

# Remove column headers
colnames(df) <- NULL


You can call renderTable with colnames = FALSE.

Thank worked thank you
